# PDO: Difference between binding params and concatenating string

Tags: php, pdo, concatenation

I have this weird problem. Why do these two implementations return different results?

```
    $db = DbBase::getInstance();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT round(round(9.50 * :amount, 2) * 23 * 0.01, 2)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':amount' => 1));
    echo $stmt->fetchColumn();

    Result: 2.18

    $db = DbBase::getInstance();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT round(round(9.50 * 1, 2) * 23 * 0.01, 2)');
    $stmt->execute();
    echo $stmt->fetchColumn();

    Result: 2.19
```

When I bind the amount it gives me different result. I'd rather not concatenate the string because of the SQL injections.

Comment: What's "behind" $db? A sqlite, MySQL, postgresql, ??? connection?

Comment: MySQL and it is a wrapper for PDO.

Answer (score 4):

When you are using the array to pass the data, the data is passed as a string:

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.

However, when you are manually entering in the `1` into the query directly it is being treated as an int. Let me see if I can do some further digging to see what happens internally when a string is converted into an int for you.

Edit: This is probably one of the [most similar bugs](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62861) that have been submitted and accepted:

```
1)
SET @a = 1;
SELECT @a;

2)
SET @a = 1.1;
SELECT @a;

.. and this 

3)
SET @a = 1.1;
SELECT @a + 7;
returns '8.100000000000000000000000000000'
(probably the addition will convert "1.1" to a double, the result 
of the addition is also a DOUBLE and finally the DOUBLE is converted 
to a string - that should be OK as well as far as I can understand)
```

So it looks like internally mysql is converting to a double when you pass it an int. That would explain rather nicely the behavior that you are seeing.

Here is a list of other similar (numbers not quite right) bugs you might be interested in:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46037

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35071

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35071 <-- Good one showing difference between Win and Lin

And a [filtered list of data type bugs](http://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=bound+parameter+does+not+give+same+result+as+int&status=Active&severity=&limit=All&order_by=&cmd=display&direction=ASC&bug_type=Server%3A+Types&os=0&phpver=&bug_age=0) that I perused which make for interesting reading.

Edit 2: Aha!

Here is a [bug that rather perfectly](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639) explains your issue:

```
Reproduce code:
---------------
CREATE TABLE my_db.my_table (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

<?php
$DB = new PDO('mysql:dbname=my_db;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$stmt = $DB->prepare('select * from my_table where id>?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, 13);
$stmt->execute();
?>

or

<?php
$DB = new PDO('mysql:dbname=my_db;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$stmt = $DB->prepare('select * from my_table where id>?');
$stmt->execute(array(13));
?>

Expected result:
----------------
select * from my_table where id>13

Actual result:
--------------
select * from my_table where id>'13'
```

Comment: +1 for "Let me see if I can do some further digging to see what happens internally when a string is converted into an int for you." WAITING  :)

Comment: @swapnesh Yeah, I love to find out how things work on the inside with these sorts of gems :)

Comment: Well I have to correct my question. Actually I want to bind float values and I couldnt find a way to do it.

Comment: @PPPHP That might change things quite a bit then (for the worse for you) Floats will be even *less* accurate when you pass them through. Can you not get away with decimals in your database instead?

Comment: @PPPHP "Fluffeh" is quite right this may render your proximity of the required data

Comment: @PPPHP See Edit 2 for rather spot on details of what is happening in the background.

Comment: @Fluffeh im unable to +1 it more for the nice and time exhausting search result :)

Comment: @swapnesh All good, I don't answer here just to get rep. I love to learn these things - and what better way than to dig into problems that interest me just as much as the OP :) Having found the details for this bug, I will be able to deal with it better in my own code moving forward.