# PHP/MySQL ignoring digits to the right of the decimal point

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point

I wrote a code that lets the user vote for one out of the two options and the score is calculated using a modified Elo rating system. However, digits to the right of the decimal point are ignored when I vote for either of the options. I added the floatval function but it didn't help.

```
$query = "SELECT pic,score,id FROM nfl
    JOIN (SELECT r1.random_id
         FROM nfl_map AS r1
         JOIN (SELECT (RAND() *
                      (SELECT MAX(row_id)
                         FROM nfl_map)) AS row_id)
               AS r2
        WHERE r1.row_id >= r2.row_id
        ORDER BY r1.row_id ASC
        LIMIT 1) as rows ON (id = random_id)";

    $query_2 = "SELECT pic,score,id FROM nfl
    JOIN (SELECT r1.random_id
         FROM nfl_map AS r1
         JOIN (SELECT (RAND() *
                      (SELECT MAX(row_id)
                         FROM nfl_map)) AS row_id)
               AS r2
        WHERE r1.row_id >= r2.row_id
        ORDER BY r1.row_id ASC
        LIMIT 1) as rows ON (id = random_id)";
    $res_2 = $mysqli->query($query_2);
    if (!$res_2) die ("Result display failed: " . $mysqli->errno . " - " . $mysqli->error);
    $pic_2 = $res_2->fetch_assoc();
    $id_2 = $res_2->fetch_assoc();
    $score_2 = $res_2->fetch_assoc();


    $res_1 = $mysqli->query($query);
    if (!$res_1) die ("Result display failed: " . $mysqli->errno . " - " . $mysqli->error);
    $pic_1 = $res_1->fetch_assoc();
    $id_1 = $res_1->fetch_assoc();
    $score_1 = $res_1->fetch_assoc();
    $Ra = $score_1;
    $Rb = $score_2;
    $calc_pow_1 = (($Rb - $Ra) / 400);
    $calc_pow_2 = (($Ra - $Rb) / 400);
    $float_calc_pow_1 = floatval($calc_pow_1);
    $float_calc_pow_2 = floatval($calc_pow_2);
    $Ea = 1 / (1 + pow(10,$float_calc_pow_1));
    $Eb = 1 / (1 + pow(10,$float_calc_pow_2));
    $float_Ea = floatval($Ea);
    $float_Eb = floatval($Eb);

    // if user votes for picture no. 1
    if (isset($_POST['vote_1']) && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['score']))
    {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    /* $score = $_POST['score'];
    $pic = $_POST['pic']; */
    //$mod = 2 * $Eb;
    $K = 4;
    $float_mod_1 = floatval($K * (1 - $float_Ea));

    $query = "UPDATE nfl SET score=?+$float_mod_1 WHERE id=?";
    // $score_new = $_POST['score'] + $mod;
    $score_new = $_POST['score'] + $float_mod_1;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('di', $_POST['score'], $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->errno) {
        echo "Vote failed: " . $stmt->error();
    }
    else echo "Vote succeeded! New score of $id_1 is $score_new!

";
    $stmt->close();
    }

    // fetch picture no. 2
    // 
    // query to the database
    /* $query_2 = "SELECT pic,score,id FROM nfl
    JOIN (SELECT r1.random_id
         FROM nfl_map AS r1
         JOIN (SELECT (RAND() *
                      (SELECT MAX(row_id)
                         FROM nfl_map)) AS row_id)
               AS r2
        WHERE r1.row_id >= r2.row_id
        ORDER BY r1.row_id ASC
        LIMIT 1) as rows ON (id = random_id)";
    $res_2 = $mysqli->query($query_2);
    if (!$res_2) die ("Result display failed: " . $mysqli->errno . " - " . $mysqli->error);
    $pic_2 = $res_2->fetch_assoc();
    $id_2 = $res_2->fetch_assoc();
    $score_2 = $res_2->fetch_assoc(); */

    // if user votes for picture no. 2
    if (isset($_POST['vote_2']) && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['score']))
    {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    /* $score = $_POST['score'];
    $pic = $_POST['pic']; */
    //$mod = 2 * $Ea;
    $K = 4;
    $float_mod_2 = floatval($K * (1 - $float_Eb));

    $query = "UPDATE nfl SET score=?+$float_mod_2 WHERE id=?";
    // $score_new = $_POST['score'] + $mod;
    $score_new = $_POST['score'] + $float_mod_2;

    /*  $query = "UPDATE nfl SET score=?+1 WHERE id=?";
    $score_new = $_POST['score'] + $mod; */

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('di', $_POST['score'], $_POST['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->errno) {
        echo "Vote failed: " . $stmt->error();
    }
    else echo "Vote succeeded! New score of $id_2 is $score_new!

";
    $stmt->close();
    }
```

Here is the full code, if you need to see it: http://snipt.org/vDhj2

The code handling the situation when the user votes for the second option is pretty much the same (except $Ea changes to $Eb etc.). The 'score' row's properties in MySQL are following:

```
float(8,3) not null
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm not getting the notice anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply missed a declaration in your code:

```
$res_1 = $mysqli->query($query);
if (!$res_1) die ("Result display failed: " . $mysqli->errno . " - " . $mysqli->error);
$pic_1 = $res_1->fetch_assoc();
$id_1 = $res_1->fetch_assoc();
$score_1 = $res_1->fetch_assoc();
$Ra = $score_1;
$Rb = $score_2;
```

I cannot see `$score_2` defined anywhere in the code above where you try to assign it's value to another variable.

Warnings are there for a reason - ignoring them is a bad idea as it will inevitably lead to an error in your code. in this case, you simply need to declare your variable before you assign it (even if it is si,ply `$score_2=0;` if that is to be the default value, but assign it nonetheless.

Comment: It looks like I fixed the notice. Not getting it anymore. Thanks to all three of you guys. But how can I fix the other issue?

Comment: @Pawel I am not entirely certain in this case, but you may want to look at [this question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155465/pdo-difference-between-binding-params-and-concatenating-string/12155531#12155531) which deals with bound parameters being treated as strings unless exactly specified as something else. It may well be an internal mysql problem that is causing it to do an integer operation and losing the data after the decimal point (but again, I am not certain of this in regards to this question)

Comment: I'm quite new to PHP & MySQL so I might be wrong but my code explicitly states: `$stmt->bind_param('ii', $_POST['score'], $_POST['id']);`
If that was the issue, shouldn't this bit of code fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> Since it's just a notice, does it matter? If so, what should I change
>   in my code?

incorrectly written code that throws an error needs to be fixed.

you cannot assign `$Rb = $score_2` before you create the `$score_2` variable -- that is an error. put them in the right order to solve that problem

Answer (score 1):

Getting a notice in PHP isn't an ERROR obviously, it's just ugly and can burden your load...

the notice you're getting means that you're using a non-set variable, doing a `var_dump(isset($score_2))` will result in bool(false), meaning that it wasn't set.

PHP is a dynamically typed language, meaning that you don't have to declare variables prior to using them, however - it's a good practise if you do, to avoid such notices which could result in errors you simply need to declare the variable prior to using it.

are you expecting a number? 
initialize it so

```
$score_2 = 0;
```

or

```
$score_2 = null;
```

depends on your needs, if you fill it with null, don't forget to allow in mysql NULL values...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it. It was a stupid mistake with fetch_assoc() etc. Here is the revised code: http://snipt.org/vEaj7